# for codeigniter 3 is there any form validation library that works for arabic?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-form-validation

Issue with Codeigniter (Version 3.1.7) Form Validation Library:

For a multi-language(english and arabic) site, i used existing form validation library - which is working fine for english.

But, for arabic language, some of the form validation(listed below) does not work 
(as it validate english characters).

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#rule-reference

Below are the methods:
alpha
alpha_numeric
alpha_numeric_spaces
alpha_dash
required

Can anyone help me to figure out this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

just like this:

you can copy and change the value

```
system/language/english copy to application/language/arabic
```

Comment: But, For Example "alpha_numeric_spaces" i wants to allow only english (a-z), arabic alphabets, 0 to 9 digit, spaces. How can get it?